# Selecting certain zero elements from a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Suppose I have this matrix:

```
M =

90     0    40     0
 0     0    10    60
55    15     0    10
 0    15     5     0
```

I would like to find all zeroes such that once I select a zero from row `i` and column `j`, **no more zeroes from row `i` and column `j` should be selected**.  In this example, scanning from left to right and top to bottom, the rows and columns I should get are:

```
Row    Column
 1        2
 2        1
 3        3
 4        4
```

What MATLAB code will produce this for me?

Comment: Did you try anything? Have you looked at `find`? Please at least attempt it, this isn't hard. Show some effort on your part. If have tried, please add to question what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry it's a bit unclear on what you wish to do.  Are you saying that for each row index dictated by `A`, you want to find **one** zero over all of the columns dictated by each row index in B?  Can it be **any** index?  FWIW, this is very basic and fundamental MATLAB syntax.  Not knowing how to do this means you have little to no understanding of the language at all.

Comment: That didn't answer my question.  Also, please update your post with new code and not *using comments*.  Lines of code beyond 2 lines look like garbage in commants

Comment: zeroRows = [];
for i = 1:size(M,1)
    for j = 1:size(M,2)
    if (M(i,j)==0)
        zeroRows = [zeroRows; [i j]];
       
    end
    end
end    it gives indices of all zeros. All i want is select one zero from each row and column at a time. if it selects zero from second column of 1st row, then it should not select another zero from 1st rows and second column.. Sorry, I am just a beginner in matlab programming...

Comment: Update your post with this information, or I won't be able to help you answer it and this will remain closed.

Comment: @user3727259 Firstly, please rather edit your question to add that code as it's difficult to read it in the comments. Secondly, it's still not clear, please also provide the exact solution that you want for that matrix. How many zeros exactly do you expect it to find? 1? 3? If you edit your question with your code and the exact solution you expect we can nominate it to be reopened so people can try answer you

Comment: The OP basically wants to select zeroes in the matrix scanning from left to right, and top to bottom such that once a zero is selected from row `i` and column `j`, **no more zeroes should be selected from all of row `i` and all of column `j`**

Comment: @user3727259 : I have edited your post to make it clear, but this question will continue to be closed.  As such, I recommend you delete this question and start a new one **with** the edits I have made to your question.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks alot.. Thats exactly what i wanted to ask.. sorry for my inability to communicate it clearly

Comment: @user3727259 No problem.  Make a new question and I will answer it.  I have a solution for you.

Comment: @rayryeng but (4,4) is neither the first zero in it's row, nor the first in it's column. So I'm not really sure that that's right :/ which is why I asked. user3727259 do you definitely want (4,4) to be selected? Also rather let the OP edit it and have it reopened than reasking the same question.

Comment: @Dan: The OP has changed his/her question, so it's no longer the first.  You're also right.  OP, please verify if what I said about your question is correct.

Comment: @rayryeng corrected my question, thats what i wanted to ask. but I cannot ask another question for next 90 mins. so i will have to wait.

Comment: I have voted to reopen.  Once it reopens I'll post my answer.

Comment: I need to go to bed, so what I will do is show you the source here.  `rowCoords` contains the final row and column co-ordinates of what you want.  The first column is the rows, while the second column is the columns.  I'm not sure if this will reopen on time.  Good luck!  http://pastebin.com/4rH6fwDh

Comment: `[ind1, ind2] = max(M.'==0); result = [find(ind1); ind2(ind1)].'`

Comment: @LuisMendo :  Nice, but using the matrix that was defined above, it locates `(4,1)` as a zero when it shouldn't be :(.  Can you fix it?  I'm still trying to understand how you did this myself.

Comment: @rayryeng Why shouldn't it? I understand the OP wants the first zero in each row. So (4,1) is ok... right?

Comment: @LuisMendo In his comments, he changed what he wanted. Once you find a zero at row `i` and column `j`, no more zeroes should be selected from all of row `i` and all of column `j`.  As such, once you find a zero at `(2,1)`, `(4,1)` should not be selected.

Comment: @rayryeng Oohh... tricky then

Comment: @LuisMendo : Yes :(  My solution I had to use a `for` loop.  I couldn't figure out any other way to do it.  I would like the OP to clarify if this is what he wanted, or if what he wanted regarding the first zero of each row is what he wanted.  He still hasn't done that yet!

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, if that's so, it seems hard to avoid a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luis Mendo's answer is correct given the OP's original question of selecting the **first** zero of each row.  However, with our discussion seen in the comments, this requirement has now changed.  The understanding (at least from what I gathered from the snippets of code and the requirements) is that once you select a zero at row `i` and column `j`, **no more zeroes from all of row `i` and all of column `j` should be selected**.  As `for` loops are usually frowned upon in MATLAB, I saw no other choice but to do this with loops.

My approach was the following:

1. Find all zeroes in the matrix and find their row and column locations and place each into separate lists.
2. While we still have a zero to consider:

   - Place this row and column into a list
   - Remove all indices from the row list that contain this row in question.
   - Remove all indices from the column list that contain this column in question
3. Repeat Step #2 until our row and column location list is empty.

Without further ado, here is the code.

```
clear all;
close all;

M =[90,0,40,0;0,0,10,60;55,15,0,10;0,15,5,0];

%// Find row and column locations
%// find traverses columns first, so I had to
%// transpose and swap J,I so that it reports
%// row locations first.
[J,I] = find(M.' == 0);

%// List of co-ordinates that meet our criteria
rowCoords = [];

%// While there is still one zero to consider...
while (~isempty(I) && ~isempty(J))
    %// Store these for processing
    rowToAdd = I(1);
    colToAdd = J(1);
    %// Add to the list
    rowCoords = [rowCoords; [rowToAdd colToAdd]];  

    %// Remove all row and column co-ordinates
    %// that share the same row and column
    rowsToRemove = I == rowToAdd | J == colToAdd;
    I(rowsToRemove) = [];
    J(rowsToRemove) = [];
end
```

As such, we finally get:

```
rowCoords = 

 1        2
 2        1
 3        3
 4        4
```

It is still unclear on whether the OP wants what Luis Mendo has provided, or what I have interpreted in the comments.  The OP verified that how I specified his requirements is what he actually wants but we still do not have any verification.  OP: Please verify.

Comment: is right...once I select a zero at row i and column j, no more zeroes from all of row i and all of column j should be selected.. the code you have given works perfect for the given matrix.. Thank you

Comment: @Ateeq You are welcome.  If this helped you, please consider accepting my answer.  Click on the checkmark icon just below the up and down voting arrows at the top left of my post.

Answer (score 1):

**Find the first zero (if any) in each row**

```
[ind1, ind2] = max(M.'==0);
result = [find(ind1); ind2(ind1)].';
```

In your example, this gives

```
result =
     1     2
     2     1
     3     3
     4     1
```

---

**Find the first zero (if any) in each row, ignoring columns that have been previously used**

```
M2 = M; %// make a copy of M2. It will be overwritten
[R C] = size(M2);
cols = NaN(R,1); %// initiallize. This will store the result for each row
ind = false(R,1); %// intiallize. This will indicate rows that have a valid zero
for r = 1:R %// for each row
    c = find(M2(r,:)==0,1); %// find first valid zero, if any
    if ~isempty(c)
        cols(r) = c; %// store result
        ind(r) = true; %// this row has been found to have a valid zero
        M2(:,c) = inf; %// this col can no longer be used
    end
end
result = [find(ind) cols(ind)]; %// build result. Only rows with a valid zero
```

In your example:

```
result =
     1     2
     2     1
     3     3
     4     4
```